# weird dot when i press my space key Spyder-IDE

Tags: spyder, space

I opened up Spyder-IDE and every time i press on my space key this is what happens:

[image]

i get this weird dot...

is it possibe to remove this dot from spyder?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You probably activated that feature yourself in the menu `Source > Show blank spaces`. I say it because we don't show those dots by default.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba  can you turn it into a awnser so i can verify it :)

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Those dots are displayed when you activate the option called `Show blank spaces`, which is present in the `Source` menu.

So you need to deactivate that option to hide them from view.